# MySQL datetime comparison

Tags: mysql, datetime

this is my problem:

I have a table in my mysql database which contains some products, and it has two columns called "date_from" and "date_to" which determine the period when the product is active.

On my website a have a form where the admin can choose two datetime values and if the product's active period intersects the span that the admin chose, the page updates a product list.

This is my query, which I am using to achieve what I want:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM presents WHERE (date_from>".$date_from." AND date_to<".$date_to.") OR (date_from>".$date_from." AND date_to>".$date_to.") OR (date_from<".$date_from." AND date_to>".$date_to.") OR (date_from<".$date_from." AND date_to<".$date_to.")";
```

I get this error though:

> mysql said: MySql error number: 1064 MySql error decription: You have
>   an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.26. 12:11:43
>   AND date_to<2012.07.30. 12:11:46) OR (date_from>2012.07.26. 12:11:' at
>   line 1

Any ideas?

*EDIT

I changed the query as suggested and added single quotes to variables. Now I don't get the error, but the query doesn't seem to do what it's supposed to - the product list stayes the same... Here's the query now:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM presents WHERE (date_from>'".$date_from."' AND date_to<'".$date_to."') OR (date_from>'".$date_from."' AND date_to>'".$date_to."') OR (date_from<'".$date_from."' AND date_to>'".$date_to."') OR (date_from<'".$date_from."' AND date_to<'".$date_to."')";
```

Let's say I have this row in my table:

ID  Name          date_from               date_to

1   test      2012-07-24 16:40:00    2012-07-31 16:40:00

---

I need all of these periods to return the row:

2012-07-23 16:40:00  to  2012-08-01 16:40:00

2012-07-23 16:40:00  to  2012-07-28 16:40:00

2012-07-26 16:40:00  to  2012-07-28 16:40:00

2012-07-26 16:40:00  to  2012-08-01 16:40:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to quote your variable.

But it is better not to concat sql, use placeholders instead.

Comment: I'll comment here since there are a lot of answers. Single quotes solved the error issue. Now I don't get the error, but the update doesn't do what it's supposed to, either... It just refreshes the page, but the product list is the same... And my datetimes are formatted like this: "YYYY:mm:dd HH:MM:SS", both in the database and on the form

Comment: @MarkoCakic What do you suppose this query to do ?

Comment: One the page with the form with datetime pickers, I also have a product list which shows all the products in the database. When the datetimes are picked, and the submit button for the form is clicked, the query should update the product list with only those products that  meet the criteria of the query

Comment: I solved the problem I had with another query, but I'll choose your answer since it solved the first issue I had, and you were the first to respond. A big thank you to everyone who responded, though

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you need to wrap your dates in single quotes:

```
date_from > '".$date_from."' AND
```

Answer (score 1):

You should enclose date in quotes like `'".$date_from."'`

EDIT: try:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM presents WHERE '".$date_from."' BETWEEN date_from AND date_to";
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [Date and Time Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-literals.html):

> MySQL recognizes [`DATETIME`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) and [`TIMESTAMP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) values in these formats:
>
> - As a string in either `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` or `'YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` format. A “relaxed” syntax is permitted here, too: Any punctuation character may be used as the delimiter between date parts or time parts. For example, `'2012-12-31 11:30:45'`, `'2012^12^31 11+30+45'`, `'2012/12/31 11*30*45'`, and `'2012@12@31 11^30^45'` are equivalent.
> - As a string with no delimiters in either `'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS'` or `'YYMMDDHHMMSS'` format, provided that the string makes sense as a date. For example, `'20070523091528'` and `'070523091528'` are interpreted as `'2007-05-23 09:15:28'`, but `'071122129015'` is illegal (it has a nonsensical minute part) and becomes `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`.
> - As a number in either `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` or `YYMMDDHHMMSS` format, provided that the number makes sense as a date. For example, `19830905132800` and `830905132800` are interpreted as `'1983-09-05 13:28:00'`.

If you are using a string format, you must ensure that your strings are properly quoted.

Comment: I'll comment here since there are a lot of answers. Single quotes solved the error issue. Now I don't get the error, but the update doesn't do what it's supposed to, either... It just refreshes the page, but the product list is the same... And my datetimes are formatted like this: "YYYY:mm:dd HH:MM:SS", both in the database and on the form

Answer (score 1):

You're passing datetimes in form of `string`, hence you need to quote them with single-quote character like this:

```
... (date_from<'".$date_from."' AND date_to>'".$date_to."') ...
```

Alternatively, you can change the format of the variables you use to be a number (in `YYYYMMDDHHmmss` form) and then quoting is not necessary

Comment: Well, your list of conditions covers (almost?) any possible scenario... it's both `from>from and to<to` and `from<from and to>to` etc..

Comment: Yes it's because I have two time periods, and I need to cover all the cases when they intersect (when the period chosen by the admin contains the period in the database, when it is contained in it, and when they intersect from both the "date_from" and "date_to" side, if I am explaining it right...)

Answer (score 0):

Try using another syntax more like :

```
WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN '01/01/2006' AND '01/02/2006'
```

Source : http://www.demiliani.com/blog/archive/2006/01/19/3384.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Here is completed version of the SQL for you :). I have created test table with the fields you have mentioned and this SQL runs perfect for me --

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM presents WHERE (date_from > STR_TO_DATE('".$date_from."', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AND date_to < STR_TO_DATE('".$date_to."', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) OR (date_from > STR_TO_DATE('".$date_from."', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AND date_to >  STR_TO_DATE('".$date_to."', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') ) OR (date_from < STR_TO_DATE('".$date_from."', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AND date_to > STR_TO_DATE('".$date_to."', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) OR (date_from < STR_TO_DATE('".$date_from."', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AND date_to <STR_TO_DATE('".$date_to."', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))";
```

Attached what I get while I run the SQL in phpMyAdmin-
[image]

Let me know if you face any issue with this.